80s/90s sci-fi/horror - Nerd's body is invaded by wires that cause his head to pop off, and vampire kills students, crosses out yearbook pics

Live action movie set in America in full English, color film, most
likely 80s or early 90s.  
I saw it on TV (could possibly be a
made-for-TV-movie), maybe on a network station sometime between
1990-1995, most likely 1993 (I would only be 9 years old then).  
It was a
late-night broadcast, between 8pm-midnight.

General plot:
This is very loose for me because I only saw parts of it. At least part of the movie was maybe about a teen vampire (or some nefarious teen-like agent) systematically murdering high school students through various brutal or supernatural means.
I recall two scenes, the first is vague and the second is slightly more memorable.
First scene

A teenage boy (vampire?) is with a teenage girl, possibly somewhere in a high school in front of a mirror. The girl is in front of the mirror with the boy behind her. The boy fixates on her neck/shoulder area while the girl looks at him quizzically in the mirror. The boy possibly draws his (sharp?) fingers along her skin, maybe drawing blood, before the scene switches to a closeup of a school yearbook page showing the girl's picture. A hand (probably the boy's) draws an X on her picture, possibly in blood, indicating that she has probably been killed.
This same type of event is repeated a few times with different people: the boy is shown together with someone, then subsequently draws an X on their yearbook picture.

Second scene

A classic 80's nerd (probably thick, black-rimmmed glasses, white t-shirt or collared shirt) is playing a video game in a home bedroom or office. The video game is Space Invaders/Galaga/Galaxian-like (black space background, ship at the bottom of the screen firing lasers at aliens above) on an Atari 2600-like machine (it could just be an 80's computer, but the joystick was Atari 2600-ish). He's very focused on his game and is eating oreos or some other junk food regularly. Without his noticing, tentacle-like computer/electrical wires (these may have been corrugated, flexible, metal wire tubes, pictured below) start to slip out of the computer/video game console. It's like the wires are alive or their being controlled by a poltergeist. A few cuts of the camera show the wires snake slowly along the desk as they move towards the nerd. 
While this is happening, other events similar to the first scene may be happening, with the movie cutting back and forth between the nerd and those scenes.
After a few cuts back-and-forth, some of the wires reach the nerds right or left hand, which is possibly resting by cookies or some junk food. The wires seem to disappear under his hand/arm, like they're digging into or merging into his wrist. At this point, the nerd has taken notice and is becoming very distraught by the wires, but he doesn't make any move to escape, possibly because he's scared stiff.
A few more first-scene-like cuts happen, sometimes coming back for a second or two to show the nerd being very distraught.
Finally, the nerd is shown again. A split second later, his head pops off, showing wires coming up out of his neck, possibly indicating that the wires took over his whole body and killed him in the process.



Gotta say, it sounds like you're conflating two different movies here.

I'll be honest, that never even occurred to me until you mentioned it. I could well have stitched a few different channels together in my memories over the years. I still think it was the same movie because #1) we didn't change channels at all from what I recall and #2) it was a summer night, not a Halloween horror movie extravaganza or anything. Nonetheless, I can't be sure.

Second scene sounds very similar to the bike death in the 5th Elm St. film (WARNING: GORY), but it's not a nerd nor a video game.

You're right, it is similar with the wires coming out of the motorcycle and digging into his body. If my mystery movie(s) exists, maybe it was inspired by Dan's death, or vice-versa.

I'm the same age as you and I remember these scenes too. I remember it seeming slightly comical. Anyhoos I done some digging with what you supplied combined with what I recall and found out it's monster high, released 1989.
http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0097905/
A quick google image search brought about many 'I remember that' feelings.
